# PermissionError: Permission denied: 'geckodriver.log' when using Selenium to open Firefox

Tags: python, permissions, geckodriver

I'm working on Chapter 11 of Automate the Boring Stuff and I'm attempting to follow along with the examples that involve Selenium. I am using a MacBook Air with Python 3.9.1 64-bit, as well as Visual Studio Code for background. I've been having a lot of issues with this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser=webdriver.Firefox()
```

From what I've researched, in order to execute the above code, I need to install both selenium and geckodriver. I found one site that lays out some instructions nicely: https://medium.com/dropout-analytics/selenium-and-geckodriver-on-mac-b411dbfe61bc.

According to the instructions on the above site, I went to: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases and downloaded 'geckodriver-v0.30.0-macos.tar.gz' and 'geckodriver-v0.30.0-linux64.tar.gz' (I wasn't really sure which version was appropriate for my situation). I went back to the Terminal window and ran `sudo nano /etc/paths` and added both `/usr/local/bin/geckodriver` and `/Users/myname/Downloads/geckodriver` to the System PATH, following the instructions.

I then attempted the first code again and I encountered the following error message (edit: I forgot to mention that the Firefox browser didn't open as desired):

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> browser=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 170, in __init__
    self.service = Service(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/service.py", line 50, in __init__
    log_file = open(log_path, "a+") if log_path else None
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'geckodriver.log'
```

This is where I'm really at a loss. I assume the error is telling me that 'geckodriver.log' needs to be moved to another directory that I have permissions to use it (/usr/local/bin??) but I have encountered errors when attempting to do so.

```
import shutil
>>> shutil.move('/Users/myname/geckodriver.log', '/usr/local/bin')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/shutil.py", line 806, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/atsushiidobe/geckodriver.log' -> '/usr/local/bin/geckodriver.log'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/shutil.py", line 820, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/shutil.py", line 435, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/shutil.py", line 264, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/geckodriver.log'
```

I would really appreciate it if anyone has any suggestions on how to solve this issue. I've looked at quite a few YouTube videos and online posts about how to install geckodriver and yet I haven't managed to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you placed the path of geckodriver in the Env Variables. once that is done perform a restart and let me know

Comment: @PSR I did add the path of gecko driver to the env variables but it still didn't work. What do you mean by "perform a restart" though? From my understanding, if I add the path of geckodriver and then close Terminal, the path will be deleted from the env variables.

Comment: "Perform a restart" => system reboot/ reboot your computer/ restart your computer

Comment: Also, from your comment, I am not sure if you are adding geckodriver PATH to the Env Variables correctly. I hope you are doing it like this =>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83SccoBYSfA

Comment: There is no terminal involved when adding PATH to Env Variables (or atleast I am not aware of such a method). Please refer the video I have linked and then, "perform a restart" (refer above to see what this means)

Comment: @PSR I'm trying to follow the video you linked but it describes the instructions for Windows 10, so I'm having difficulty attempting to replicate the instructions from that video on my MacBook.

Comment: Does this help ? => https://phoenixnap.com/kb/set-environment-variable-mac

Comment: @PSR Just for reference, I am following this site with instructions on how to use env variables in Terminal on MacBook: https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/use-environment-variables-apd382cc5fa-4f58-4449-b20a-41c53c006f8f/mac. The instructions here mention that you have to enter the appropriate command in Terminal in order to add PATH to env variables.

Comment: Ok go ahead, let me know if things work out

Comment: @PSR Now I get this error message when I try the code: `>>>from selenium import webdriver  >>>browser=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=/usr/local/bin/geckodriver` `DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object`. I've tried to look at ways to solve this new error message but I still haven't found a good solution as of yet.

Comment: OK, so now it's just a version thing. I think it should still work (It works for me). If not try to find out the latest syntax.

Comment: @PSR I want to thank you for taking the time to help me. I got the code to run properly by deleting all of my previous 'geckodriver' files and starting over.

Comment: Always happy to help. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Option 1

The quick way to install geckodriver properly, without fussing about architectures by manually installing everything is by using homebrew:

Go to https://brew.sh/ and install homebrew.

Then, you should be able to run the following command:

`brew install geckodriver`

Which will install the geckodriver binary to a location on your $PATH (by default, `/usr/local/bin`).

Let's make sure we have the right version of the binary:

If you have a MacOS computer from ~2006-2020, you have an Intel Mac.
If you have a MacOS computer from ~2020+, you have an M1 Mac, aka an arm64 or aarch64 mac

If you have an Intel Mac:

Run the following, and it should print this out:

```sh
$ file /usr/local/bin/geckodriver
/usr/local/bin/geckodriver: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

With an M1 Mac:

```sh
$ file /usr/local/bin/geckodriver
/usr/local/bin/geckodriver: Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64
```

Great, if that worked, we have the correct version of the binary.

To run selenium, you'll have to install it (which I presume you've done, but if you haven't, run `pip3 install selenium`).

Then run the following code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
browser=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
<stdin>:1: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object # Browser opens. Ignore this warning, it doesn't really matter.
```

It should print a deprecation warning, but that doesn't really matter.

## Option 2

Otherwise, you can fuss about architectures:

Let's go to the releases page of geckodriver:

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/latest

There are a few choices of download:

Linux(32|64) means linux 32 bit or linux 64 bit. On MacOS, this isn't important, so lets ignore these.

```
geckodriver-v0.30.0-linux32.tar.gz 
geckodriver-v0.30.0-linux32.tar.gz.asc 
geckodriver-v0.30.0-linux64.tar.gz
geckodriver-v0.30.0-linux64.tar.gz.asc
```

These are for MacOS, so lets look at these:

```
geckodriver-v0.30.0-macos-aarch64.tar.gz 
geckodriver-v0.30.0-macos.tar.gz
```

Win32 and Win64 are for windows, so let's ignore those as well.

```
geckodriver-v0.30.0-win32.zip 
geckodriver-v0.30.0-win64.zip
```

As above, note what architecture your MacOS is running.

If you have an intel mac, download and unarchive `geckodriver-v0.30.0-macos.tar.gz`.
If you have an arm64 mac, download and unarchive `geckodriver-v0.30.0-macos-aarch64.tar.gz`.

Afterwards, (I'm going to presume the binary is in `~/Downloads`):

Move it from `~/Downloads` to somewhere on your $PATH, like `/usr/local/bin`.

```sh
$ mv ~/Downloads/geckodriver /usr/local/bin
```

Now geckodriver is on your $PATH.

To run selenium, you'll have to install it (which I presume you've done, but if you haven't, run `pip3 install selenium`).

Then run the following code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
browser=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
<stdin>:1: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object # Browser opens. Ignore this warning, it doesn't really matter.
```

It should print a deprecation warning, but that doesn't really matter.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to respond. I think I had too many versions of gecko driver saved in my folders and that may have been the source of confusion. When I deleted all of them and started over following Option 2, the code worked like it was supposed to and Firefox browser opened.